# $\ell(f)>\int_{a}^{b}||f'(t)||dt$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, arc-length

We know that if $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a $C^1$ path then
$$\ell(f)=\int_{a}^{b}\|f'(t)\|dt.$$

Moreover, in the proof of this result we use explicitly the continuity of $f'.$

I'm trying to find an example of a differentiable function (at every point of $[a,b]$) such that $f':[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is not continuous and
$$\ell(f) > \int_{a}^{b} \|f'(t)\|dt.$$

I found this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2902711/the-length-of-a-regular-curve-is-different-from-its-measure-for-rectifiable-no), but if I'm not mistaken, the Cantor function is not differentiable at every point.

Can anyone help me with this example?

Comment: $l(f)$ is only defined when $f$ is path $\mathcal{C}^1$ and continuous (or at least absolutely continuous), don't you mean $d(f(a),f(b))$ instead of $l(f)$ ?

Comment: @Cactus Let $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ a path and $P=\{a_0=a<a_1<\cdots <a_n=b\}$ be a partition of $[a,b]$. We define $\ell(f,P)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \|f(t_i)-f(t_{i-1})\|$. We say that $f$ is a rectifiable curve if $\{\ell(f,P)\}$ is bounded for all partitions $P$ of $[a,b]$. In this case, we define $\ell(f)=\sup_{P}\ell(f,P)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a curve does not exist. When $f$ is differentiable, we always have the bound
$$
\ell(f) \leq \int_a^b \|f'(t)\|\,dt.
$$
To see this, consider a partition $a = t_0 < \dots < t_n = b$ of $[a, b]$. Using the fundamental theorem of calculus, we can write
$$
f(t_{i + 1}) - f(t_i) = \int_{t_i}^{t_{i + 1}} f'(t)\,dt,
$$
where each side of the equation is vector-valued. By the [triangle inequality for vector-valued integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240935/inequality-involving-the-integral-of-vector-valued-function), we get
$$
\|f(t_{i + 1}) - f(t_i)\|
= \left\|\int_{t_i}^{t_{i + 1}} f'(t)\,dt\right\|
\leq \int_{t_i}^{t_{i + 1}}\|f'(t)\|\,dt.
$$
It follows that
$$
\sum_i \|f(t_{i + 1}) - f(t_i)\|
\leq \int_a^b\|f'(t)\|\,dt.
$$
Taking a supremum of the LHS, we obtain the inequality above.

**Edit:** As pointed out in the comments, we have to be careful when applying the fundamental theorem of calculus in the above proof when $f'$ is not Riemann integrable. It turns out that the (second) fundamental theorem of calculus holds iff $f$ is *absolutely continuous* (see Theorem 7.18 of Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*). Moreover, if $f$ is everywhere differentiable and $f'$ is $L^1$, then $f$ is absolutely continuous (see Theorem 7.21 of Rudin). Therefore, the only case where the fundamental theorem of calculus fails is when $f'$ is not $L^1$, in which case the RHS of the inequality above is $\infty$.

Comment: What about $\int_{c}^{d} f'(t)dt$ if $f'$ is not continuous, how do you apply the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus? Maybe the integral isn't even defined.

Comment: The FTC is still true without the continuity assumption as long as your function is Riemann integrable.

Comment: Differentiability alone is not sufficient for FTC. If Riemann inetgrability of $f'$ is assumed it should be made epxlicit in the answer. This is only a partial answer.  @dezdichado

Comment: I agree with you @geetha290krm

Comment: @geetha290krm ok you're right I mixed the premises of the question and the answer

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the extra assumption. I've edited my answer with some clarification—the proof should work if we use some powerful results :)

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to impose any additional assumptions. I'm really looking for some counterexample, if any.

Comment: @Math23 My answer (after the edit) doesn’t involve any additional assumptions, so you won’t be able to find a counterexample.